# Can't change Image during onclick event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have added image & button dynamically to a webpage. I wrote a "onclick" event, by which the image will be changed on clicking respective button. But the code doesn't work.

My code is;

```
 <style>
 .tableclass{
 height:80px;}
 .imgclass{
 height:50px;
 width:50px;} </style>
 <script>
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = "Images/circle.png";
 img.className = 'imgclass';

 window.onload = function init() {
 for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
 var container = document.getElementById('body');
 var table = document.createElement('table');
 table.className = 'tableclass';
 var tr = document.createElement('tr');
 var td = document.createElement('td');
 var btn = document.createElement('input');
 btn.type = 'button';
 btn.className = 'buttonclass';
 td.appendChild(btn);
 td.appendChild(img);
 tr.appendChild(td);
 table.appendChild(tr);
 container.appendChild(table);
 }
 }
 btn.onclick = function(){
 document.getElementsByClassName('imgclass').src = "Images/square.jpeg";
 }; 
 </script>
 <body id="body"></body>
```

Comment: Try using JQuery, it makes using Javascript a breeze, along with HTML DOM manipulation!

Comment: have you got an element with id of body or are you refering to `<body> `tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding an event to...

```
boton.onclick
```

But I think your variable is named `buton` - so you need to use:

```
buton.onclick
```

Also, as this is running in the loop, you probably want to add the onclick event to each one you create (so put the event binding inside the loop).

Here is a running version of the script:

```
function getImage() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "Images/circle.png";
    img.className = 'imgclass';
    return img;
}

function getRow() {
    var img = getImage();
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var buton = document.createElement('input');
    buton.type = 'button';
    buton.className = 'buttonclass';
    buton.onclick = function(){
        img.src = "Images/square.jpeg";
    };
    td.appendChild(buton);
    td.appendChild(img);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    return tr;
}

var container = document.getElementById('body');
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.className = 'tableclass';
for(var i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    table.appendChild(getRow());
}

container.appendChild(table);
```

You can [see it running on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNqT8/).

Comment: you really need to check your spellings, and try and be as accurate as possible!

Comment: @user2546074 check out the fully working example I have added to my answer - it has the spellings fixed, moves the event binding to inside the loop and uses function-scope to make it easier to target just the image in the same table row.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not a single element.

You may do this :

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('imgclass');
for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) imgs[i].src = "Images/square.jpeg";
```

But it would be probably cleaner to give an id to your image and use `getElementById`.

Note also that you seem to hesitate on the spelling of `botón`/`boton`/`buton` and that will make it hard for the code to work. You should see errors [in the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

Comment: sorry.It's buton.onclick = function()

Comment: @user2546074 you have other occurrences of the same error, like `td.appendChild(botón);`.

Answer (score 0):

There boton has an accent the first time you use it...and why are you using a for loop? I think an array of images could work and every time you click it increments a counter which changes the image. Also use .jpg not .jpeg

Answer (score 0):

This is closer to the original -- I just removed the for loop because I didn't see the need for it...

```
<style>
.tableclass{
height:80px;}
.imgclass{
height:50px;
width:50px;} </style>
<script>

var count = 0;
var images = [];
images[0] = "Pictures/1.jpg";
images[1] = "Pictures/2.jpg";
images[2] = "Pictures/3.jpg";
images[3] = "Pictures/4.jpg";

var img = new Image();
img.src = images[count];
img.className = "imgclass";

window.onload = function init() {

var container = document.getElementById('body');
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.className = 'tableclass';
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var td = document.createElement('td');
var button = document.createElement('input');
button.type = 'button';
button.className = 'buttonclass';
button.onclick = function(){buttonClick();}
td.appendChild(button);
td.appendChild(img);
tr.appendChild(td);
table.appendChild(tr);
container.appendChild(table);

}

function buttonClick(){
if(count < images.length - 1){
count++;
}else{
    count = 0;
}
img.src = images[count];
}; 
</script>
<body id="body"></body>
```